# kotlin.time.Duration cannot be converted with room ksp

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I've been trying to use `kotlin.time.Duration` with android's room database using :

```kotlin
object DurationConverter {
    @JvmStatic
    @TypeConverter
    fun toDuration(millis: Long?): Duration? = millis?.milliseconds

    @JvmStatic
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromDuration(duration: Duration?): Long? = duration?.inWholeMilliseconds
}
```

I have associated it with my database like so :

```kotlin
@Database(
    entities = [ /* entities */ ],
    version = 1
)
@TypeConverters(DurationConverter::clas)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() { /* daos */ }
```

However, on compilation ksp is throwing this error :

```
[ksp] .../db/codec/DurationConverter.kt:7: Class is referenced as a converter but it does not have any converter methods.
```

Which seems to indicate that something is wrong with my converter. However, I have other converters looking like the DurationConverter working well.

Example :

```kotlin
object InstantConverter {
    @JvmStatic
    @TypeConverter
    fun toInstant(epoch: Long?): Instant? = epoch?.let(Instant::ofEpochMilli)

    @JvmStatic
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromInstant(instant: Instant?): Long? = instant?.toEpochMilli()
}
```

The same error occurs when I use a class instead of an object :

```kotlin
class DurationConverter {
    @TypeConverter
    fun toDuration(millis: Long?): Duration? = millis?.milliseconds

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromDuration(duration: Duration?): Long? = duration?.inWholeMilliseconds
}
```

How can I make the converter to works ?

---

Plugin versions used :

```kotlin
val roomVersion = "2.5.2"
id("com.android.application") version "8.1.0" apply false
id("com.android.library") version "8.1.0" apply false
id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.8.22" apply false
id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.8.22-1.0.11" apply false
```

Room dependencies:

```kotlin
val roomVersion = "2.5.2"
implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$roomVersion")
ksp("androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion")
implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:$roomVersion")
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Room, but those methods being `static` is strange. Wouldn't it be more logical to implement some `Converter` interface on your object?

Comment: In most of other framework it would be the case, however the [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/referencing-data) explains converters that way...

Comment: i suggest to delete annotation processor because ksp is a compiler too

Comment: The annotation processor can indeed be deleted safely, thank you. But it do not fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This happening because `kotlin.time.Duration` is a [value class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-classes.html), meaning it's a simple wrapper of some value that will be inlined during compilation. So in your case, you're trying to convert Long to Long.

Consider using Duration from Java or try to save Duration as it is in the DB without converters.